# AdjustText TypeError: query_pairs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'output_type'

Tags: matplotlib, scipy, overlapping

I'm trying to use the adjustText library with matplotlib to remove overlapping text.
I'm using Python==3.8, matplotlib==1.5.0, adjustText==1.0.4, and scipy==1.5.3
For additional context, I'm running in Azure on the Python 3.8-AzureML Kernel.
Could someone please recommend how to get around this issue?
I'm not attached to using the adjsutText library with matplotlib, so if anyone's got other suggestions for how to fix overlapping text annotations, please let me know!! Thank you

This is the code I'm running:

```
def pca_biplot(original_transformed_clusters_df, num_dims, pca_components):
    
    from adjustText import adjust_text
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
    
    dim_1 = original_transformed_clusters_df.iloc[:,20:21]
    dim_2 = original_transformed_clusters_df.iloc[:,21:22]
    
    components_transposed = np.transpose(pca_components[:3,:])
    num_features = components_transposed.shape[0]
    features_names = list(original_transformed_clusters_df.columns[10:20])
         
    scale_dim_1 = dim_1/(dim_1.max()-dim_1.min())
    scale_dim_2 = dim_2/(dim_2.max()-dim_2.min())
    
    plt.scatter(scale_dim_1, scale_dim_2, c = original_transformed_clusters_df['Cluster Labels'], alpha=0.2)
    
    texts = []
    
    for i in list(range(num_features)):
        
        dx = components_transposed[i,0]
        dy = components_transposed[i,1]

        plt.arrow(0, 0, dx, dy, color = 'r', lw=1, head_width=.008, head_length=.01)
        
        texts.append(plt.text(dx*1.05, dy*1.05, features_names[i], fontsize=14))
            
    adjust_text(texts, only_move={'points':'dx*2', 'texts':'dy*2'}, arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='wedge', color='black', lw=1))
    
    plt.grid()
    
pca_biplot(df_x_and_pca_clustering, 3, pca.components_)
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[41], line 47
     43     adjust_text(texts)
     45     plt.grid()
---> 47 pca_biplot(df_x_and_pca_clustering, 3, pca.components_)

Cell In[41], line 43, in pca_biplot(original_transformed_clusters_df, num_dims, pca_components)
     40 plt.xlabel('DIM1', fontsize=14)
     41 plt.ylabel('DIM2', fontsize=14)
---> 43 adjust_text(texts)
     45 plt.grid()

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/adjustText/__init__.py:505, in adjust_text(texts, x, y, objects, avoid_self, force_text, force_static, force_pull, force_explode, expand, explode_radius, ensure_inside_axes, expand_axes, only_move, ax, min_arrow_len, time_lim, iter_lim, *args, **kwargs)
    501     explode_radius = max(
    502         (coords[:, 1] - coords[:, 0]).max(), (coords[:, 3] - coords[:, 2]).max()
    503     )
    504 if explode_radius > 0 and np.all(np.asarray(force_explode) > 0):
--> 505     explode_x, explode_y = explode(coords, static_coords, explode_radius)
    506     if "x" not in only_move["explode"]:
    507         explode_x = np.zeros_like(explode_x)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/adjustText/__init__.py:243, in explode(coords, static_coords, r)
    241     points = np.vstack([points, static_centers])
    242 tree = scipy.spatial.KDTree(points)
--> 243 pairs = tree.query_pairs(r, output_type="ndarray")
    244 pairs = pairs[pairs[:, 0] < N]
    245 pairs = pairs[pairs[:, 0] != pairs[:, 1]]

TypeError: query_pairs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'output_type'
```

Previously, this code worked fine when I had Python==3.9.15, matplotlib==3.6.2, adjustText== 0.7.3.1, and scipy==1.10.0, but this was on my local machine. I've now started working in Azure and I'm not sure how to fix the problem.